# SQL <= shows also the rows that are equal to the value

Tags: sql

I am trying to run an SQL statement. I want to select the rows where `paid` lower is than `total`.

If `total` = 500 and `paid` = 0 the SQL shows the row.
When `total` = 500 and `paid` = 500 the row is also shown.

I also dont want to show the row where `total` is equal to `paid`. Do I need to add an `IS NOT ==` or is there a more practically way to define this in the SQL statement?

Here is my SQL statement:

```
SELECT id, name, total, paid FROM invoice WHERE paid <= total
```

Comment: `WHERE paid < total`. `<=` is the *"less-than-**or-equal-to**"* operator. See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-operators.htm

Comment: That is a logical impossibility

Comment: Sorry, It worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is Worked. like this,
 Select *
from Invoice i
where i.paid <= i.total

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) ! Please read  [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) ?